# designer shows A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject error

Tags: c#, wpf

I've created a user control that has a DependencyProperty, and when I try binding to it I get an error in the designer:

> " 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'ROCValue' property of type
>   'RocIndicator'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of
>   a DependencyObject.

**Edit:** I've added the static modifier, but I still get that error. and yes, I've restarted visual studio.

```
public partial class RocIndicator : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ROCValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ROCValue", typeof(double), typeof(RocIndicator),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0, new PropertyChangedCallback(ValueChanged)));


    public double ROCValue
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ROCValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ROCValueProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

this is the XAML:

```
<View:RocIndicator ROCValue="{Binding ROC}" Margin="0,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="35"/>
```

but when I build & run it works. why is this error showing?

Comment: As far as i can see, your dependencyProperty is correct. Normally this Exception appears when `DependencyProperty.Register("ROCValue"`the Register is with false Name `"ROCValue"`

Comment: Did you restart your Visual Studio ?

Comment: @S.L. i restarted it several times, and added the "static" i missed, but i still get that error.

Comment: I copied your code and my designer says everything is okay

Comment: Try Clean and Rebuild your Solution

Comment: i tried rebuilding, and restarting the computer, nothing works.
i have lots of dependency properties, so i can't figure out why this one isn't working

Comment: Did you try a Clean on your Solution ?

Comment: @S.L. yes, and it didnt help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dependency property declaration must be `static`:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ROCValueProperty ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue once when copying a UserControl from one project to another. I tried closing the solution, restarting Visual Studio and even restarting my PC. None of those worked.

I then unloaded and reloaded the project and this seemed to fix it. (Potentially a Visual Studio build bug).

To unload the project, right click on your project in Solution Explorer and click 'Unload Project'.
Then right click again and click 'Reload Project'.

Answer (score 0):

For each xaml form, *.g.cs and *.g.i.cs files are automatically created in the /objs/Debug/*/ folder. Sometimes some of these files are not actualized by the "Rebuild Solution" option.

I could not yet identify when this happens.

But I solved it by deleting the **"obj"** folder in the project directory and rebuilding the solution.

Comment: Welcome to SO! May you shortly explain your solution, please?

Comment: @B--rian For each **xaml** form, *.g.cs and *.g.i.cs files are automatically created in the `/objs/Debug/*/` folder.
Sometimes some of these files are not autalized by the "Rebuild Solution" option.

I could not yet identify when this happens.